# Script with awk is not working with Crontab

Tags: bash, awk, cron, cron-task

i have created a script.awk that generate selected lines from my cfg file and then copy the resulting data on separate file(extract.cfg). The problem is that bash script is working perfect from terminal but when i try to use this via crontab, it does nothing. here is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash  
awk -v expireDate="$(date +%F\ %T)" -f /var/etc/script.awk /var/etc/input.cfg > var/etc/extract.cfg
```

Here is my script.awk

```
BEGIN { 
    FPAT="[[:digit:]]{4}-[^}]+"; # assign enddate sting to $1  
    }  
    $1 >= expireDate { # for lines with enddate >= expireDate  
    print;         # print this line  
    }
```

in crontab i am using

```
*/1 * * * * /etc/test.sh
```

i am expecting that extracted data should be save on new file named as extract.cfg every 1 minute. but crontab do nothing

Comment: Look like a working directory problem. `cd` to the correct directory in your Bash.

Comment: Use full path, no relative path: `var/etc/extract.cfg`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have already edited my bash script with directory. My bash script is working perfect when executing from terminal i.e ./test.sh

Comment: I think i have to put some enviroment that support awk to run with cron but i don't know how to put awk enviroment on my bash.

Comment: Just specify the full path to gawk instead of just using `awk`.

Comment: run `which awk` and use the full path outputted from the `which`. And also, to debug crontab, you can print the output to a file: `*/1 * * * * /etc/test.sh
 | /usr/bin/logger -s -t "my-test"`

Comment: You can debug with a crontab like `date > /tmp/date_test.wrk`, next put this line inside your `/etc/test.sh` and keep changing the commands step by step until it looks like what you want.

Comment: I like your idea of debugging but i don't understand how to do this. Would you please explain clearly how to put ithis in my bash?

Comment: How do you call your bash script? Does it have execution permission?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have solved my problem, actually my script.awk don't have executing enviroment,due to this reason my crontab not running awk script. Simply adding this line at the beginning solved my problem.
    #!/usr/bin/awk -f